# What's the track when Burnham goes into the future?

Tags: star-trek-discovery, music-identification

In [this scene](https://youtu.be/B05d3CsAnrY?t=17) from Star Trek: Discovery Season 2 finale. It starts 17 seconds in, when she signals the Discovery to follow her.

I attempted to search for it myself and came across [Time Traveller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRJJMyUmOBc), but that's not it. That's when she has to close the loop before going into the future.

Comment: You might have better luck at MusicFans.SE

Comment: @Paulie_D - I'll leave it up for another hour and then try MusicFans.SE.